# Pulling Data off a Weather API and tweeting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm setting up a twitter bot to tweet out the temperature of a city, any idea why my setup function isn't working?

I tried changing to a different API but nothing seems to work.

```
console.log('starting twitter bot...')

var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);


setup();


function setup() {

  loadJSON("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=###############&q=Colombo", gotData);

}


function gotData(data) {
  console.log('Weather Data Retrieved...')

  var r = data.current[2];

  var tweet = {
    status: 'here is ' + r + ' temperature test '
  }

  T.post('statuses/update', tweet);

}
```

I get this error:

**ReferenceError: loadJSON is not defined**

Comment: Where's your function `loadJSON`? Because the error you're receiving is that `loadJSON` doesn't exist?

Comment: I see, so should add this :                                                                         
  `function loadJSON(path, success, error) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      }
      else {
        error(xhr);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', path, true);
  xhr.send();
}`

Comment: I'd certainly give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the request library to pull the weather conditions, in particular use the [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) library, this makes it very easy to read API data:

Just do:

```
npm install request
npm install request-promise-native
```

To install, then:

```
const API_KEY = '7165..'; // Put your API key here
const Twit = require('twit');
const config = require('./config');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function testWeatherTweet(location) {
    const options = {
        url: "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json",
        qs: { 
            key: API_KEY,
            q: location
        },
        json: true
    };
    let result = await rp(options);
    let condition = result.current.condition.text;
    let tweetText = `Conditions in ${location} are currently ${condition}, temperature is ${result.current.temp_c}°C.`;
    console.log("Sending tweet: ", tweetText);
    sendTweet(tweetText)
}

function sendTweet(text) {
    const T = new Twit(config);
    const tweet = {
        status: text
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet);
}

testWeatherTweet('Colombo');
```

Comment: Great! I might just suggest you take down your API key from the question,  you probably don't want it to be used by others!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using p5.js? You should note that p5 won't run on node server side as it is dependent on accessing the window object. Hence loadJSON function is undefined.

you could use XMLHttpRequest for retrieving data.

```
 function setup() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

  request.open('GET', 'https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=############################&q=Colombo', true)
  request.onload = function() {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      gotData(data)
    } else {
      console.log('error')
    }
  }

  request.send()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!